# Is there any software to code html css etc at the same time i see how my page is going?

Tags: html

I'm a teenager starting in coding, and I'm interested in some kind of software that shows me how my html page would look at the same time I code the css, html, js, etc files. Can i get some recomendations? Thanks, Ralph.

Answer (score 1):

[VSCode](https://code.visualstudio.com/) will do this with an extension. I just confirmed it works with [this one](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=george-alisson.html-preview-vscode), however I see it looks like there's something like 100 of them if I search the marketplace.

Comment: I mean it does show the HTML but it doesn't show it with CSS too, do I have to enable something or it just cant do it?

Comment: Ok, I found one that does it, "Live Previw" by microsoft. Ty

Answer (score 1):

If you have a large enough screen, you could do it yourself:

- 1 window for editing the HTML.
- 1 window for editing the CSS.
- 1 window for the browser.

The `<head>` of the HTML should contain:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5" />
```

to refresh the page every 5 seconds.

That allows you to control the refresh time and the size, shape, and location of the windows.