# Free wysiwyg HTML javascrtipt editor that allows source code edit?

Tags: web-development, wysiwyg

I am looking for an editor for a blog site and time to time the users need to insert and later on also edit  tag into the post. But in a way that the script actually works.

Does any editor allow users to insert and save working  tag? Something like TinyMCE. https://www.tiny.cloud/blog/source-code-editing/ I do not like their pricing structure. Quill would be the best choice for me but https://github.com/quilljs/quill/issues/128

Note that I am selling subscription to the site so I am not sure if I can use CKEditor 5 because of GPL 2+

**update**

I did my research and explore

1. tinyMCE - 1000 loads per month might not be enough
2. quill - does not support inserting of  tag
3. trix - does not support inserting of  tag
4. editor.js - finding out if it supports inserting tag
5. brackets - finding out
6. ContentTool - looks promising. But I am not sure about the UI. Looks bit complicated for my target users
7. CKEditor - finding out if it supports insering tag
8. Froala - pricing
9. summernote - finding out
10. Pell - not developed anymore??
11. jodit - finding out
12. suneditor - finding out
13. ProseMirror - finding out

Comment: Relevant: https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/87504/recommended-html-editor

Comment: Also relevant: https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/84071/is-there-any-software-to-code-html-css-etc-at-the-same-time-i-see-how-my-page-is

Comment: Possibly useful Google search: https://www.google.com/search?q=free+html+editor